# Creating a custom string sort list for bubble sort

Tags: excel, vba

I get the gist of bubble sort but I'm struggling of finding a way to implement "string 1" > "String 2". I'll start off by describing my workbook.

My workbook is a shared excel file used to track everyone's day-to-day project progress. Every day at noon the workbook will add a new column with the days date into column G. Because of this there is no definite right end to the workbook due to it adding one column every day. Rows 1 through 11 are frozen and are filled with non project specific info (e.g. legend, a message board, buttons for other macros, column headers)

Each project in the workbook takes up three rows (ex. rows 12-14 is the first project listed, rows 15-17 is the second project listed). Column A has the rows "Status", "Start Date", and "End Date". My aim is to sort the projects by status. The status cell has a drop-down list with six different options: "R" fur running", "S" for setup", "H" for hold, "P" for report, "U" for upcoming, and "C" for complete. This is also the order I hope to sort the projects by.

I found I version of bubble sort I'm planning to implement [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/348760-function-bubble-sort-three-numbers.html). The sub from this post is:

```
 '============================================================================
 '- BUBBLE SORT EXAMPLE : 3 NUMBERS (ASCENDING)
 '- The method is to use a "pointer" and check its current position in the array.
 '- If the current number is more than the next then switch their positions in the array.
 '- If a position is changed then set a marker so the pointer goes through again.
 '- The sort is complete when the pointer has gone through the array without change.
 '- Brian Baulsom October 2008  
 '=============================================================================

 Sub SORT_()
     Dim MyNumbers(3)
     Dim Pointer As Integer
     Dim Changed As Boolean
     Dim MyTemp
     '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     MyNumbers(1) = 30
     MyNumbers(2) = 20
     MyNumbers(3) = 10
     '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Do
         Changed = False
         For Pointer = 1 To 3 - 1
             If MyNumbers(Pointer) > MyNumbers(Pointer + 1) Then
                 MyTemp = MyNumbers(Pointer)
                 MyNumbers(Pointer) = MyNumbers(Pointer + 1)
                 MyNumbers(Pointer + 1) = MyTemp
                 Changed = True
             End If
         Next
     Loop While Changed = True
     '-------------------------------------------------------------------------
     MsgBox (MyNumbers(1) & vbCr & MyNumbers(2) & vbCr & MyNumbers(3) & vbCr)
 End Sub
 '============================================================================
```

With this I plan on changing how it changes the sorted number to instead cut and paste.

I know I can't just put If "P" > "C" without it throwing errors. So where I'm at now is figuring out how to give each of the strings values I can sort by while still (preferably) only having one IF loop.

Do the numbers saved as MyNumbers(1), MyNumbers(2) sort by the number index or the .Value? If it sorts by index then there shouldn't be a problem with creating:

```
 MyNumbers(1) = "R"
 MyNumbers(2) = "S"
 MyNumbers(3) = "H"
 MyNumbers(4) = "P"
 MyNumbers(5) = "U"
 MyNumbers(6) = "C"
```

but I'm still unfamiliar enough with VBA to figure this out easily.

Comment: You can sort letters, too.  Try changing `MyNumbers(1)` to `R` and so on and giving it a try.

Comment: Use the [StrComp function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function)?

Comment: Thanks for the info and suggestions. I will try these and see what works.

Comment: Why not? `if "A" < "B" then debug.Print "A<B"`
 => result: A<B

Comment: Why not? `if "P" > "C" then debug.Print "P>C"`
 => result: P>C